# Using more than one field with IN ( ) for a sub-query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, I would have to do something like:

```
SELECT hits.item.productName
FROM [‘Dataset Name’ ]
WHERE date, visitId, fullVisitorId IN (
  SELECT date, visitId, fullVisitorId
  FROM [‘Dataset Name’ ]
  WHERE hits.item.productName CONTAINS 'Product Item Name A'
  AND totals.transactions>=1)
```

However, this does not seem to be supported. What alternatives do I have besides using a JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a JOIN instead.

The equivalent of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), stn, a.wban, FIRST(name) name, FIRST(country) country
FROM [fh-bigquery:weather_gsod.gsod2014] a
WHERE stn, wban IN
  (SELECT usaf, wban FROM [fh-bigquery:weather_gsod.stations] WHERE country='UK')
GROUP BY 2, 3
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), stn, a.wban, FIRST(name) name, FIRST(country) country
FROM [fh-bigquery:weather_gsod.gsod2014] a
JOIN [fh-bigquery:weather_gsod.stations] b
ON a.stn=b.usaf AND a.wban=b.wban
WHERE country='UK'
GROUP BY 2, 3
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know a JOIN works, but are there no alternatives to this?

Comment: A very ugly alternative would involve concatenating the values of date, visitId and fullVisitorId. I would like to avoid this as well.

Comment: Behind the scenes the IN clause is implemented as semijoin, so you really don't lose anything by using JOIN explicitly.